# The type 'ISomeService' is not an service interface as it does not derive from the interface 'INonServiceFabricService'

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have the following setup:

```
public interface ISomeService : IService, INonServiceFabricService
{
}
```

Where `INonServiceFabricService` is an interface with no Service Fabric dependencies to allow me to de-couple my application code from infrastructure:

```
public interface INonServiceFabricService
{
    Task DoSomething();
}
```

My implementation then inherits from `ISomeService`:

```
public class ActualService : StatefulService, ISomeService 
{
    public Task DoSomething()
    {
        // Something
    }
}
```

Everything builds and runs fine but when I try to create a proxy:

```
var proxy = ServiceProxy.Create<ISomeService>(Uri, new ServicePartitionKey(0));
```

I get the following error:

> The type 'ISomeService' is not an service interface as it does not
>   derive from the interface 'INonServiceFabricService'

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out it isn't possible to do this.

Every interface your Service Fabric service interface (e.g, `ISomeService` in question)  inherits from must derive from `IService`. See [here](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/55).

The error should really say:

> The type 'INonServiceFabricService' is not an service interface as it
>   does not derive from the interface 'IService'